# React array state not pushing value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to update my state array with new values. Basically, I want to add some new values to the array. but couldn't able to do that

```
const [values, setValues] = useState(["data1", "data2"]);

const newData = [["data 43", "data 1.1"],["data 65", "data 2.2"] ]

newData.map((item) => {
  setValues([...values, item[1]]);
});
 
returns ["data1", "data2", "data2.2"]
```

what i want is `["data1", "data2", "data 1.1", "data 2.2"]`
I just want to store 2nd value of array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

1. Using `Array.prototype.map` is for mapping an existing array to a new array, not for issuing side-effects like updating React state or pushing into other array.
2. When enqueuing state updates in a loop you *must* use a functional state update to correctly update from the previous state instead of the state from the previous render cycle.

## Solution

```
const [values, setValues] = useState(["data1", "data2"]);

...

["data3", "data4", "data5"].forEach((item) => {
  setValues(values => [...values, item]);
});
```

Since you are really just appending one array to the other you can make this simpler by removing the looping. (*Well, you are still looping, but now the loop is within the state updater function so you avoid the state-looping issue*)

```
setValues(values => [...values, ...["data3", "data4", "data5"]]);
```

or

```
setValues(values => values.concat(["data3", "data4", "data5"]));
```

### UPDATE

Use the functional state update to shallow copy the previous `values` and map the new data to an array of ***just*** the second element and shallow copy *that* new result.

```
const newData = [
  ["data 1", "data 1.1"],
  ["data 2", "data 2.2"]
];

...

const [values, setValues] = useState(["data 1", "data 2"]);

...

setValues((values) => [
  ...values,
  ...newData.map(([, newValue]) => newValue) // *
]);
```

* `newData` is an array of arrays, `[, newValue]` in the callback uses destructuring assignment to "skip" the 0th element and assigns the 1th element to a variable `newValue` and returns this value for the mapping.

#### Edit

To remove duplicates created in new data, use a `Set` to remove them:

```
setValues((values) => [
  ...new Set([...values, ...newData.map(([, newValue]) => newValue)])
]);
```

#### Demo

[image: Edit react-array-state-not-pushing-value]

Comment: hey thanks for solution but i did a mistake on data i have updated the question please check

Comment: @geekglance So you want to ignore "data 1" and "data 2" or is this another typo?

Comment: Yes, I want to ignore them.  So I just need to update the 2nd value of the array.

Comment: @geekglance I see, and updated my answer and attached codesandbox.

Comment: So when i update newData it updateS the state with previous one. So there is an issue of duplicate values. How can i reslove that ?

Comment: @geekglance Use a Javascript `Set` to serialize/deserialize the state update to remove duplicate entries. I'm curious though, shallow copying the previous state shouldn't be creating duplicates, so they must be coming in via the new data. The `Set` can resolve this, but maybe you're updating your state *oddly*?

Answer (score 1):

```
const newArr = ['data3','data4','data5'];

setValues((prev)=>([...prev, ...newArr]));
```

You can do like this

### UPDATED

```
const newData = [["data 43", "data 1.1"],["data 65", "data 2.2"] ]
setValues((prev)=>([...prev, ...newData.flat()]));
```

Comment: hey thanks for solution but i did a mistake on data i have updated the question please check

Answer (score 0):

If all nested arrays will be of equal length you can use something like this to iterate over

```js
newData = [["data 1", "data 1.1"],["data 2", "data 2.2"]]
const rowLength = newData[0].length
const returnArr = []
for(let i=0; i<rowLength; i++){
  returnArr.push(newData.map(row => row[i]))
}
console.log(returnArr.flat())
```

Answer (score 0):

`setData` comes from your `useState` and is kind of asynchrone. You can't use it in a loop. What you want to do is prepare your final data object, and call `setData` only once with it.

```js
// No change here
const [values, setValues] = useState(["data1", "data2"]);
const newData = [["data 1", "data 1.1"],["data 2", "data 2.2"] ]

// Flatten the array
const finalData = newData.flat();

// Update the state only once
setValues(finalData);
```